# How is it possible to quantify the strength of a Lewis acid/base?

Tags: acid-base

When the $pK_a$ scale is not applicable - when there is no proton/charged species transfer - what should be used to quantify the strength of an acid?

Comment: see Gutmann–Beckett method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann%E2%80%93Beckett_method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\ce{A~  + :\!\!B -> \ \ A\!\leftarrow:\!\!B}$$

$$K_f = \dfrac{\ce{[A\!\leftarrow:\!\!B]}}{\ce{[A][B]}}$$

See sections 4.1 and 4.2 in the following reference for more information:

http://goicoechea.chem.ox.ac.uk/teaching/abse/abse_lecture2.pdf

But $K_f$ is specific to an acid-base pair.

A more universal scale is formed by the [Gutmann–Beckett method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann%E2%80%93Beckett_method) by observing the phosphorous NMR spectrum of triethylphosphine oxide as it interacts with a sample lewis acid.

An Acceptor Number (AN) scale is formed with AN=0 corresponding to triethylphosphine oxide in hexane (P chemical shift of 41), and AN = 2.21 (d-41), where d is the chemical shift of triethylphosphine oxide interacting with the sample. The greater AN is, the more acidic the compound.